# Authenticating Office 365 SharePoint Online OOTB services

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api, office365

I want to consume SharePoint data into a non .Net platform. I already use the SharePoint OOTB services like Lists.asmx, Webs.asmx and search.asmx for this purpose.
I have successfully added support for forms based authentication using Authentication.asmx.
Now, I want to provide support for Office 365 SharePoint online. For that purpose I have a demo SharePoint Online site that I am working on.
Problem, I am facing is when I use Mode method of Authentication.asmx I get ‘Forms’ in response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <ModeResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
        <ModeResult>Forms</ModeResult>
    </ModeResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However when I use Login.asmx and pass correct username and password, I get ‘PasswordNotMatch’ error, the same credentials are working fine in browser.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <LoginResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
        <LoginResult>
         <ErrorCode>PasswordNotMatch</ErrorCode>
            <TimeoutSeconds>0</TimeoutSeconds>
        </LoginResult>
    </LoginResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Note:- This works perfect for a FBA non Office 365 SharePoint site.

Could somebody please help me in implementing the support for Office 365 SharePoint Online OOTB services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been looking into a similar idea and [this thread](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sharepoint%20reuse%20cookiecontainer&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDcQFjAD&url=http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/624.aspx&ei=JTS9TsfuJc-gtge8g4GeBg&usg=AFQjCNEGMBapb4jEVEb-pSOJ7m8QxC0azw) has been extremely helpful. They actually have a webservice sample using the PInvoke, it might help you get there.

**Edit:** my search led me to [this other post by Wictor Wilen](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx), but trying to avoid the ClientOM for now.

**Edit2:** alright, got this working. Using the code from Wictor above, I downloaded his sample solution and moved "MsOnlineClaimsHelper.cs" and "WcfClientContracts.cs" to my project, I will be fiddling with what is really used from these files later. I only changed them to remove the ClientOM references including the clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest method.

In a sample MVC3 app or Console app:

```
MsOnlineClaimsHelper claimsHelper = new MsOnlineClaimsHelper("https://my365site.sharepoint.com/sites/enterprise/", "admin@my365site.onmicrosoft.com", "secret");

using (var lists = new SharePointLists.Lists())
{
    lists.Url = @"https://my365site.sharepoint.com/sites/enterprise/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
    lists.CookieContainer = claimsHelper.CookieContainer;
    var listCol = lists.GetListCollection();
    ViewBag.Message = listCol.InnerXml;
    //Console.Write(listCol.InnerXml);
}
```

Comment: @Kuldeep Shige, how would I get authenticated with Form Based type on Office 365 using SOAP? I've tried to send a valid SOAP request with username/password to "Authentication.asmx", but got "PasswordNotMatch".

Comment: Not sure, is it a simple password? I'd look at encoding and then try to get the docs to see if they expect the password or a hashed version of it.

Comment: @F.Aquino: Wictors Code is not working in few cases of Office 365. I am getting this error "Access denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first browse to the web site and select the option to login automatically."